# Executando programas externos com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Gostaria de reduzir o tamanho de várias Mp3 em um diretorio com:

```
ffmpeg -i k.mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 16k -ar 44100 k_.mp3
```

onde K é o nome das Mp3 (k de 1 a 8):

[image: Diretorio]

Tentei o seguinte código:

```
    import subprocess

for x in range(1, 9):
    r = subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", " ffmpeg -i x.mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 16k -ar 44100 x_.mp3"])
```

Depois gostaria de renomear todos os arquivos assim:

```
1_mp3 vira    Sri Harinama - Aula 1
2_mp3 vira    Sri Harinama - Aula 2
3_mp3 vira    Sri Harinama - Aula 3
4_mp3 vira    Sri Harinama - Aula 4
5_mp3 vira    Sri Harinama - Aula 5

...
9_mp3 vira    Sri Harinama - Aula 9
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) pode executar um comando com argumentos. Para isso você precisa passar uma lista como parâmetro. O primeiro item dessa lista é o nome do comando a ser executado. Os demais itens são os argumentos desse comando.

Você passou a string `x.mp3` e `x_.mp3` como nome do arquivo de entrada e saída, respectivamente. Esses valores não serão substituídos pelo valor `x` declarado no for. Isso pode ser resolvido, por exemplo, usando-se [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) para alterar o valor de uma string e executar `ffmpeg` dinamicamente para todos os valores do `range(1, 9)`.

Tente executar dessa forma (código não testado):

```
import subprocess

input_file_fmt = '{}.mp3'
output_file_fmt = 'Sri Harinama - Aula {}.mp3'

for x in range(1, 9):
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg',
                     '-i',
                     input_file_fmt.format(x),
                     '-acodec',
                     'libmp3lame',
                     '-ac',
                     '2',
                     '-ab',
                     '16k',
                     '-ar',
                     '44100',
                     output_file_fmt.format(x)])
```

A linha 3 define a formatação do nome do arquivo de entrada. Ex.: `1.mp3`, `2.mp3`, ...

A linha 4 define a formatação do nome do arquivo de saída. Ex.: `Sri Harinama - Aula 1.mp3`, `Sri Harinama - Aula 2.mp3`, ...

Comment: obrigado. Assim que testar, volto aqui para comentar e marcar como resolvido!

Comment: :Tentei executar:http://imgur.com/a/PKLOU   mas o código não fez nada (nem deu erro também).

Comment: Está executando no mesmo diretório dos arquivos a serem processados? Coloque o script python no mesmo diretório dos arquivos ou altere o diretório de trabalho utilizando o [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir).

Comment: Dúvida de iniciante. Caso os arquivos não existam, não deveria ter uma mensagem de erro?